# Deploy SolrCloud to multiple servers

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I am a little bit confused with solrCloud. But how can I deploy SolrCloud on multiple servers? Will it be multiple nodes one per separate server or maybe will it bee one solrCloud node and multiple shards one per server?

And how all of this will communicate with Zookeeper (as far as I understand Zookeeper has to be also deployed on the separate server, is this correct?)

I am a little bit confused with all of this? Can you help me? Or maybe give a link to a good tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SolrCloud section of the reference manual should be able to help you out](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/solrcloud.html) about the concepts of Solr Cloud.

You can run multiple nodes on a single server, or you can run one node on each server. That's really up to you - but all the nodes running in a single server will disappear when that server goes down. The use case for running multiple nodes on a single server is usually for experimenting or for very particular requirements to try to get certain speedups from the single threaded parts of Lucene, so unless you're doing low-level optimization, having one node per server is what you want.

The exception to that rule is for development and experimenting - running multiple nodes on a single machine is fine when the data doesn't matter.

All the nodes make up a single SolrCloud cluster - so you'd be running multiple nodes, not multiple clusters.

Zookeeper should (usually) be deployed on three to five servers - depending on what kind of resiliency you want for failovers. While Solr bundles a Zookeeper instance you can use if you don't want to set up Zookeeper yourself, that is not recommended for production. In a production environment you'd run Zookeeper as a separate process - but that may not mean that you'll be running it on separate servers. Depending on how much traffic and use you'll see for Zookeeper for your nodes, running them on the same server as your cloud nodes will work perfectly fine. The point is to avoid using the bundled version to have full control over Zookeeper and its configuration, and to be able to upgrade/manage the instances outside of Solr.

If the need arises later you can move Zookeeper to its own cluster of servers then (at least three).

Comment: Hi @MatsLindh. Thanks for the answer. But if I want to have maximum fault tolerance I need to have one node and collections split in separate shards on multiple servers so if one server goes down I will not lose ability to search using rest shards?

Comment: In that case you're looking for the `replicationFactor`, which will determine how many different nodes each shard will be stored on. A shard is a piece of the complete collection, and the `replicationFactor` tells Solr how many nodes you want to have a copy of the shard. You set the replication factor when you create the collection.

Comment: Thanks, so as far as I understand normal installation is to deploy nodes on separate server one per server? Is it correct?

Comment: Correct, then let the instance handle multiple collections etc. as necessary. At least that's where you should start, then adjust as needed from there.

Comment: Thanks, @MatsLindh I have understood more deeply all of this staff as far as a read official documentation. Also, your comments helped me to start.